# windowExitAnimation changes after using soft keyboard

Tags: android, animation, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a custom dialog which has to slide up from the bottom of the screen, and then slide down again when it is dismissed. (similar to how the soft keyboard works).
The custom dialog contains some text fields to be filled in.

I've specified my custom dialog style with windowEnter and windowExit animations.
When the dialog is first created, it slides up and down correctly. When you dismiss it, it slides back down like it should.
But after you fill in one of the fields and close the keyboard, the dismiss animation is messed up. It slides up and dissapears instead of sliding down like it should.
So somehow the act of opening and closing the keyboard causes the windowExitAnimation to get messed up.

Here's my code:

slide_up.xml (enter animation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

slide_down.xml (exit animation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogSlideTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
    </style>
```

In the activity's manifest I have set the soft input mode to adjustNothing (because I thought maybe the keyboard is causing the layout to be recalculated and therefore the animation gets thrown off):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Like I said it works fine when you first show the dialog, only after you use the keyboard the exit animation changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @plsch have you solved this problem i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

change slide_down.xml file to following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```